# Kendo UI Mobile - Stop Scroller

Tags: listview, kendo-ui

Is there anyway to stop the scroller? For example, I would like to allow the user to return to a particular location upon touching a button. My approach so far is:

```
// scroll to the top
e.view.scroller.reset();

// scroll to the destination offset
e.view.scroller.scrollTo(0, targetOffset);
```

The problem is that if the scroller was previously scrolling, it will continue to scroll after  the targetOffset until its velocity is 0.

Could someone help me in an approach to first stop the velocity of the scroller?

I am using JQuery 1.9.1 and the Q1 2013 release of Kendo Mobile

Answer (score 2):

Though not exposed from their documentation, I solved it by setting the velocity property to 0 here:

```
e.view.scroller.yinertia.velocity = 0;
```